# How to display different iframe app for fans and non-fans?

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-graph-api

How can U display different iframe app for fans and non-fans of a page without asking user about permissions like Static Iframe Tab app (http://www.facebook.com/iframehost) is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the data you get from facebook in the so called "[signed request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)". There is a flag included that fits your needs (true if the user has liked the page, otherwise false).

Answer (score 0):

here's the code for that signed request check:

```
$signed_request = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];
function parsePageSignedRequest(){

if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])){
 $encoded_sig = null;$payload = null;
 list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
 $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
 $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));
 return $data;
}
return false;
}

if($signed_request = parsePageSignedRequest()){
  if($signed_request->page->liked) {
// put your "Liked Page Content Here" 
  } else {
// put your "Alternate" Page Content Here.
  }
}
```

Comment: You should actually better be using facebook's reference implementation.